# Hiding blockcart module while being in the check-out process

Tags: prestashop, cart

I'm working with prestashop 1.4.3. Updating to 1.5 is not a possibility.

I have the blockcart module hooked in the "Right column blocks" and in the "Header of pages". I would like to create a exception so the blockcart module doesn't show while the user is in any of the steps of the check-out process (the shopping-cart.tpl).

I have tried editing both positions (right column and header of pages) and adding "cart.php" as an exception but the module is still showing.

Any help? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cart.php is only used to update user carts, it does not provide any output to user. User shopping cart is displayed in order.php . Now if you want to hide cart block from order process or steps, then you have to add order.php into exceptions for cart block, and it will hide the cart block.

Try it and let me know if it works for you.